# How to open a document onclick of linkbutton according

Tags: c#, .net

I want to open my uploaded document in the new window based on respective linkbutton ID's. document is saved with full path in DB.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkstdres" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Alias") %>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Idinst") %>' CommandName="StudentRes" OnClick="lnkstdres_Click"></asp:LinkButton>  

protected void lnkstdres_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

i have no idea how to do that. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
if( ( File1.PostedFile != null ) && ( File1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 0 ) )
{
    string fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(File1.PostedFile.FileName);
    string SaveLocation = Server.MapPath("Data") + "\\" +  fn;
    try
    {
        File1.PostedFile.SaveAs(SaveLocation);
        Response.Write("The file has been uploaded.");
    }
    catch ( Exception ex )
    {
        Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
        //Note: Exception.Message returns a detailed message that describes the current exception. 
        //For security reasons, we do not recommend that you return Exception.Message to end users in 
        //production environments. It would be better to put a generic error message. 
    }
}
else
{
    Response.Write("Please select a file to upload.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the solution for my problem.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="grvstdRes" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover" OnRowCommand="grvstdRes_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                                                <Columns>
                                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Document">
                                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkstdres" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Alias") %>' 

CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Idinstance") %>' CommandName="StudentResAliasName" ></asp:LinkButton>
                                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                    </Columns>
                                               </asp:GridView>

   protected void grvstdRes_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    { 
        if(e.CommandName=="StudentResAliasName")
        {  
            using(objResultUnitBLL=new UnitBLL())
            {
                using(objUnitDTO=new UnitDTO())
                {
                    objUnitDTO = objResultUnitBLL.GetStudentResourceFile(Convert.ToInt64(e.CommandArgument));
                     string fileName=objUnitDTO.FileName; //to get the full path from DB
                     string[] pathArr = fileName.Split('\\'); // To split the path 
                     fileName = pathArr.Last().ToString(); //To get the file name  with extension
                     Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "OpenWindow", "window.open('../Upload/Instance/" + fileName + "','_newtab');", true); //to display the file in new window.
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```